# Option Values Deleting Automatically in OpenCart 1.5.3.1

Tags: .net, mysql, c#-4.0, opencart

I've created a crawler for website parsing. It gets the information from website and store it in OpenCart Database. What happens is that i can't view some options in product description page in opencart. But in admin panel when i edit and save those options without changing anything. Then i can view those options in product description page.

There is also another problem. Some option values randomly gets deleted from the database after i do the steps stated above and can't view the option values in the product description page associated with the option.

I'm using OpenCart Version 1.5.3.1.
And i've created this parser in C#.NET 4.0 and backend database is MYSQL.

Is this a bug?

I've posted an image here.

http://s11.postimage.org/lab58b4ip/Option_Value_Bug.jpg

Comment: It may be a bug but only in Your crawler... You should check Your crawler as I guess all the magic is done within it - crawling and storing the data...

Comment: @shadyyx I've checked & double checked the code. It is working fine and it is storing the data in database. But when i try to edit and save option in open cart those values gets deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. It is fixed by the OC people..:)

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/commit/7ba1837c93645994063a6df67638924d86b0c672

Or alternatively you can edit this:
"upload/admin/model/catalog/product.php"

```
 @@ -38,10 +38,12 @@ public function addProduct($data) {
38   38 

39   39 
           $product_option_id = $this->db->getLastId();
40   40 

41      
-          if (isset($product_option['product_option_value'])) {
     41 
+          if (isset($product_option['product_option_value']) && count($product_option['product_option_value']) > 0 ) {
42   42 
             foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
43   43 
               $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['option_value_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$product_option_value['subtract'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_option_value['price'] . "', price_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['price_prefix']) . "', points = '" . (int)$product_option_value['points'] . "', points_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['points_prefix']) . "', weight = '" . (float)$product_option_value['weight'] . "', weight_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['weight_prefix']) . "'");
44   44 
             } 
     45 
+          }else{
     46 
+            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_option_id = '".$product_option_id."'");
45   47 
           }
46   48 
         } else { 
47   49 
           $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option['option_value']) . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");
...  ...    
@@ -160,10 +162,12 @@ public function editProduct($product_id, $data) {
160  162    

161  163    
           $product_option_id = $this->db->getLastId();
162  164    

163     
-          if (isset($product_option['product_option_value'])) {
     165    
+          if (isset($product_option['product_option_value'])  && count($product_option['product_option_value']) > 0 ) {
164  166    
             foreach ($product_option['product_option_value'] as $product_option_value) {
165  167    
               $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option_value SET product_option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['product_option_value_id'] . "', product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option_id . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value_id = '" . (int)$product_option_value['option_value_id'] . "', quantity = '" . (int)$product_option_value['quantity'] . "', subtract = '" . (int)$product_option_value['subtract'] . "', price = '" . (float)$product_option_value['price'] . "', price_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['price_prefix']) . "', points = '" . (int)$product_option_value['points'] . "', points_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['points_prefix']) . "', weight = '" . (float)$product_option_value['weight'] . "', weight_prefix = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option_value['weight_prefix']) . "'");
166  168    
             }
     169    
+          }else{
     170    
+            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option WHERE product_option_id = '".$product_option_id."'");
167  171    
           }
168  172    
         } else { 
169  173    
           $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_option SET product_option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['product_option_id'] . "', product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "', option_id = '" . (int)$product_option['option_id'] . "', option_value = '" . $this->db->escape($product_option['option_value']) . "', required = '" . (int)$product_option['required'] . "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Options can appear to not be there if you don't have any items in stock for them. I believe this was intentional to hide options that weren't available. Check that you have set the stock values for each option in your product editor's "Options" tab